# How to provide actuator security in non spring-security spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How to enable security for actuator endpoints when there is no spring-security module dependency in a spring-boot **1.5.4.RELEASE** project

I have added below values in application.properties but when I click on any endpoint I get error as

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access is denied. User must have one of the these roles: ACTUATOR

security.user.password=admin
security.user.name=admin
security.user.role=ACTUATOR
management.security.roles=ACTUATOR
```

How should I enable security ?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the value, i.e. `management.security.roles=`